# Epplus date comparison does not trigger with an if

Tags: c#, if-statement, epplus

I'm trying to compare values in cells from two different spreadsheets.

Can anyone explain why this line doesn't think the values are equal (it never triggers):

```
if (destCell.Value == sourceWorksheet.Cells[1, 1].Value)
```

The actual values of each:

```
? destCell.Value
{3/31/2022 12:00:00 AM}
    Date: {3/31/2022 12:00:00 AM}
    Day: 31
    DayOfWeek: Thursday
    DayOfYear: 90
    Hour: 0
    Kind: Unspecified
    Millisecond: 0
    Minute: 0
    Month: 3
    Second: 0
    Ticks: 637842816000000000
    TimeOfDay: {00:00:00}
    Year: 2022
? sourceWorksheet.Cells[1, 1].Value
{3/31/2022 12:00:00 AM}
    Date: {3/31/2022 12:00:00 AM}
    Day: 31
    DayOfWeek: Thursday
    DayOfYear: 90
    Hour: 0
    Kind: Unspecified
    Millisecond: 0
    Minute: 0
    Month: 3
    Second: 0
    Ticks: 637842816000000000
    TimeOfDay: {00:00:00}
    Year: 2022
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Text is what I needed...

```
if (destCell.Text == sourceWorksheet.Cells[1, 1].Text)
```